Display: flex; with flex-direction: column; is shrinks elements in Firefox, but works in Google Chrome
I need my design to look the same on different browsers, but I can't find out why the same code gives me different results in different browsers. elements are shrinked in Firefox while using flex-direction: column; with display: flex;


#a-p-c {
  width: 95%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  object-fit: cover;
  contain-intrinsic-size: 150px 20px;
}

#title {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#phone {
  height: 55px;
  width: 95%;
  text-indent: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#addphone {
  height: 50px;
  width: 60%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #607D8B;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<div id="a-p-c">
  <img id="close" src="http://192.168.1.7/fullbx/icons/search-close.svg">
  <img id="logo" src="http://192.168.1.7/fullbx/icons/logo.png">
  <br>
  <span id="title">განცხადების დასამატებლად აუცილებელია ვალიდური ტელეფონის ნომრის დამატება.</span>
  <br>
  <input id="phone" type="number" placeholder="ტელეფონის ნომერი (+995)">
  <br>
  <button id="addphone">დამატება</button>
</div>



Google chrome:
Firefox: 
Sorry for the bad quality photos.

Side Note: For telephone numbers you should either use  or if you want to display numbers an anchor: <a href="tel:..."></a>

The issue is the <br> tag not working in firefox. That's why you are not seeing the same in chrome and firefox.
Using <br/> to add spacing between HTML elements is bad practice. I suggest assigning CSS padding or margins to your form elements. The following post is very informative: When to use  line breaks vs CSS positioning?


#a-p-c {
  width: 95%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  object-fit: cover;
  contain-intrinsic-size: 150px 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#title {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 10px;
}

#phone {
  height: 55px;
  width: 95%;
  text-indent: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
}

#addphone {
  height: 50px;
  width: 60%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #607D8B;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<div id="a-p-c">
  <img id="close" src="http://192.168.1.7/fullbx/icons/search-close.svg">
  <img id="logo" src="http://192.168.1.7/fullbx/icons/logo.png">
  <span id="title">განცხადების დასამატებლად აუცილებელია ვალიდური ტელეფონის ნომრის დამატება.</span>
  <input id="phone" type="number" placeholder="ტელეფონის ნომერი (+995)">
  <button id="addphone">დამატება</button>
</div>




Different browsers handle CSS differently. Try adding this to the top of your CSS file:
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

May help with consistency across different browsers
If that doesn’t work also add this to the #logo, #phone, and #addphone:
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-grow: 0;

And to the #title just:
flex-shrink: 0;

These can ensure that things aren’t unexpectedly resizing themselves.

"Try this" is not an answer. Did you actually verify if this solves the issue? Furthermore please explain why/how this would solve the issue.

@Zack Murray Thanks for the quick response, but the result is the same after adding box-sizing: border-box; also flex-shrink: 0;
flex-grow: 0; not fixing the problem

I added a couple more things to try out. Not a CSS expert honestly, those are just a couple of things I’d try if I were having this issue.

Browsers do not handle CSS differently. They have different rendering engines (Blink, Chromium, Gecko, WebKit, etc.). The rendering engines have different CSS property support and different user agents
